# In Python why doesnt this work? .... with open('filename.txt','a+').write('Some sample file content\n')

Tags: python

I know I can use the following and it nicely closes the file after writing.

```
with open('filename.txt','a+') as file_:
   file_.write('Some sample file content\n')
```

And I can even keep it on a single line in the script as follows.

```
with open('filename.txt','a+') as file_: file_.write('Some sample file content\n')
```

So both of these seem to provide or return an object type of TextIOWrapper that allows me to write to the file.

Though why can't I use this following line, or is there a similar approach that adds the write function to the object provided by the open instruction?

```
with open('filename.txt','a+').write('Some sample file content\n')
```

Comment: You can’t just call write method on contextmanager itself, you need the file object

Comment: You can, but the problem here is that `with open().write()` means that the `with` statement is trying to call the `__enter__` method of the return value of `write`, not `open`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you drop the `with`:

```
open('filename.txt','a+').write('Some sample file content\n')
```

But it will not (necessarily*) close the file.

---

```
with X as Y:
    Z
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
import sys
try:
    exc = None, None, None
    y = X.__enter__()
    Z
except Exception as e:
    exc = sys.exc_info()
finally:
    X.__exit__(*exc)
```

The object returned by `open` has an `__exit__` method defined that closes the file, so just doing `open(...).write()` won't make that happen.

---

* In a one-liner like that, CPython happens to also close the file, because the file object gets garbage-collected.

Comment: More precisely, the file will only be closed once the object returned by `open` is garbage-collected. But when that happens isn't precisely known. It could be immediately, or it could happen after a short delay. (Or, it may never happen, if the interpreter exists, though in that case, the file is closed anyway.)

Comment: @chepner Yes, I added that. CPython always garbage-collects immediately when objects go out of scope (with the exception of cyclic references which get cleaned up every so often), but that's not guaranteed for other implementations.

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks. So could you confirm the file-lock is released as soon as the write statement concludes.

Comment: @TonyB I think yes if no parent processes has a lock on the file.